# How can I scan a thing and modify it or scan two things and compare them?

Tags: scanning

I've been asking people about this, not no clue yet.

I want to scan a thing and modify it a little.

For example I have an object with 3 parts and

I want to change the position of the third part relative to the other 2 parts.

For example I have a certain object and I want to modify it a little to see

how the air flow around them would change.

Or I want to scan two similar things and see what's the difference between them

PRECISELY... is there any way to do this?

Comment: We need more detail or clarity here. The "scan and edit" thing is fairly easy, you just do a good-quality 3d scan and then edit the mesh in a 3d modeling program like you'd edit any mesh. For the second request, you can scan two things and just sit one model over the other in a modeling program to get a sense of differences. But scanning two things to QUANTITATIVELY identify differences is probably not going to happen outside a heavy-duty metrology lab or manufacturing QA/QC center. You need precision touch-probes for the level of accuracy I think you're wanting. Scans aren't all that accurate

Comment: Actually I am all new in 3D modeling and what I got from people in this area is that first of all, converting 3D scanned data to something model-able is not so easy and cutting a part of an object and replace it needs some extra work because I have to fill in the empty part caused by moving...

Comment: @RyanCarlyle it depends on what level of 3D scanner you're using, to the accuracy. I have a vision system with a touch probe and laser module at work that we've repeatedly gotten 0.0002" repeatability/accuracy with the optical measurements. KHKim 3D scanning is definitely not easy and turning the scan into a solid model can be even harder. It might help if you explain what you want to scan and how you want to scan it/them.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure what you mean by *I want to scan a thing and modify it a little to see its effect.* In general, a 3D scan typically results in a series of raw points. You'll need to convert the 3D point cloud into a Mesh before you can really do any solid modeling with it. Here are a few OpenSource programs that you could potentially use:

- [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/)
- [Blender](https://www.blender.org/)
- [CloudCompare](http://www.danielgm.net/cc/)

To compare two scans, you could use the raw data in CloudCompare as well.

However, without knowing what your intended use is, it's difficult to tell how to help you. Please consider updating your response with a bit more of your own research so that we may definitively answer your question.

Comment: I modified the question, it might be a little better now. Thank you for the answer